# files to include in app deployment

Tags: c#

I'm done with a c# application vs2012 and now I need to install it to the client which already has sql server express installed I'm including the appname.exe found in bin/release and the app.config file only. Are these files enough?

I haven't installed any external libraries, but I have a dbml file as I'm using linqtosql, and some images used in the references files should these be included as well.

And just one more thing, should I change anything in the app.config or not necessary since its a db on sql express

Visual studio doesn't need to be installed in the client PC, right?

Comment: VS does not need to be installed on the end user's PC

Comment: thanks, so the .exe found in the bin/release can be opened without vs. and how about the files to be included are the .exe and app.config enough?

Comment: There's a pretty good MSDN page about that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e(v=vs.110).aspx